# Encontrar objetos repetidos en un array javascript

Tags: javascript, json, array, nodejs

resulta que tengo un array de objetos donde me gustaría saber si una posición del array, en cuyo interior tiene un objeto, se repite con otro del mismo array.

El array sería algo así:

```js
[
  {
    "id": "990448",
    "apellidos": "Gonzalez",
    "rango": "MS"
  },
  {
    "id": "990448",
    "apellidos": "Gonzalez",
    "rango": "MS"
  },
  {
    "id": "997",
    "apellidos": "Ramirez"
    "rango": "MR"
  }
]
```

La cuestión sería resolver que el primer valor del array, y el segundo, son iguales a nivel del object.values de cada posición.

Comment: buenas, eso me lo resuelve cuando uno de los valores es igual, lo que a mí me interesa es que los dos objetos sean iguales en todos los valores de sus propiedades.

Answer (score 3):

Veo dos opciones para solucionarlo, voy a empezar con la mas generica.

Esta solución vale si quieres encontrar duplicados en toda la lista. Independientemente de si van seguidos o no.

Voy a suponer que el campo que los identifica como únicos es el `id`. Si en tu caso fueran todos los datos siempre puedes crear un hash de ellos y hacer el mismo procedimiento.

```js
users = [
  {
    "id": "997",
    "apellidos": "Ramirez",
    "rango": "MR"
  },
  {
    "id": "990448",
    "apellidos": "Gonzalez",
    "rango": "MS"
  },
  {
    "id": "990448",
    "apellidos": "Gonzalez",
    "rango": "MS"
  },
  {
    "id": "997",
    "apellidos": "Ramirez",
    "rango": "MR"
  }
]

usersById = users.reduce((acc, user) => {
  if (!acc[user.id]) {
acc[user.id] = []
  }

  acc[user.id].push(user)

  return acc
}, {})

console.log(usersById)
```

Ahora solo queda iterar sobre el mapa y aquellos que tengan más de 1 elemento están repetidos.

El segundo caso es el que (creo) estas pidiendo concretamente. Encontrar repetidos pero solo si son consecutivos. Para ello también podemos usar reduce, pero tenemos que añadir un poquito mas

```js
users = [
  {
    "id": "997",
    "apellidos": "Ramirez",
    "rango": "MR"
  },
  {
    "id": "990448",
    "apellidos": "Gonzalez",
    "rango": "MS"
  },
  {
    "id": "990448",
    "apellidos": "Gonzalez",
    "rango": "MS"
  },
  {
    "id": "997",
    "apellidos": "Ramirez",
    "rango": "MR"
  }
]

consecutiveIds = users.reduce((acc, user) => {
  if (acc.lastId == user.id) {
acc.repeatedIds.push(acc.lastId)
  }

  acc.lastId = user.id

  return acc
}, {repeatedIds: [], lastId: ""}).repeatedIds

console.log(consecutiveIds)
```

Nótese que en el segundo caso el acumulador lleva 2 datos, La lista de los ids repetidos, que es lo que nos interesa al final. Pero también cual fu el anterior id. Por lo que si es igual al actual significa que tenemos repetidos consecutivos.

Comment: buenas, en realidad lo que necesito es mirar si dentro del array, la posición por ejemplo 1 tiene un objeto dentro cuyo valores son iguales que el objeto del array que está en la posición o 4, y puede pasar varias veces. En realidad no tiene porque ser consecutivo, y el campo id en realidad me lo he inventado, nada identifica a los objetos. muchas gracias por tu tiempo, compañero.

Comment: @ArthurMorgann si nada identifica a los objetos como sabes que los "valores" son iguales? El objeto siempre tiene el mismo formato? 

La posición 1 es igual a la 4? es arbitrario que posiciones mirar? o simplemente te interesa encontrar repetidos dentro de la lista, no importa la posición? si es así el primer ejemplo es lo que buscas solo cambiando como `id` por "lo que sea que define iguales"

Comment: Viendo el comentario en tu propia pregunta. Es lo que te he dicho en la respuesta. he asumido Id pero puedes generar una función "hash" que lo unico que hace es crear un string muy largo con las key-value de cada item. y de esa forma funciona exactamente igual

Comment: Lo primero, muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Voy a explicarme mejor, a ver si consigo que se me entienda: es duplicado cuando el valor coincide en los 3 object.entries a la vez, si no, no es duplicado. Las keys siempre van a ser las mismas en todo el array de objetos.

Gracias de nuevo.

Answer (score 0):

Para el caso podes iterar 2 veces con un `forEach` y aprovechar el segundo parametro opcional del metodo , cual indica el indice actual de evaluacion del elemento , te hice unos comentarios en esa parte del codigo para que se entienda la ejecucion .

- como no se si hay que mantener el array original inmutable , lo copie con el operador de propagacion `[...arr]`
- en el resultado final te queda , el array original , el array sin elementos dulicados y un array de duplicados

```js
const array = [
    {
      "id": "990448",
      "apellidos": "Gonzalez",
      "rango": "MS"
    },
    {
      "id": "990448",
      "apellidos": "Gonzalez",
      "rango": "MS"
    },
    {
      "id": "997",
      "apellidos": "Ramirez",
      "rango": "MR",
    }

  ]

const arrSinDuplicados = [...array];
const duplicados = [];
arrSinDuplicados.forEach((el, index) => {

    const copyItem = JSON.stringify(el);
    
    arrSinDuplicados.forEach((item, indice) => {
        const itemCopy = JSON.stringify(item);
        //el elemento de por si se va a encontrar asi mismo , por eso hay que establecer  index!=indice
        if (copyItem == itemCopy && index != indice) {
            //lo que devuelve arrCopy.splice es el elemento que se encuentra duplicado
            //y lo ponemos en el array de duplicados
            duplicados.push(arrSinDuplicados.splice(indice, 1));
        }
    });
});

console.log(array);
console.log(arrSinDuplicados);
console.log(duplicados);
```